# How do I uninstall Internet Explorer 9 so I can install Internet Explorer 6?

Tags: windows-7, uninstall, internet-explorer-9

I've tried uninstalling Internet Explorer 9 in Windows 7 from Control Panel, it always produces an error and fails.
From Command Prompt, it didn't do anything. The file can not be deleted. I can move it,  and then delete it through Linux (dual-boot), on booting back into Windows, Internet Explorer 9 is there.

I want to install Internet Explorer 6 for my father for an exam he wants to take, but am unable to install it, because Internet Explorer 9 cannot be removed.  I even tried to delete the relevant registry entries with regedit, but that doesn't help either.

Is there some way to accomplish this?  If not, are there other solutions I should be considering?

Comment: "it always produced an error" and what was the error text?

Comment: Have you tried [the MS Knowledge Base article on the subject](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2579295)?

Comment: Well, no a very specific error, just that it can't be removed... And yes, I have, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Antoni4040 - IE6 **CANNOT** be installed on Windows 7. You would be better off using the free virtual machine that is offered to test IE6.  I should point out IE9 can be removed but since you provided us no information on the error we really can't help with that particular problem.

Comment: Use Windows XP Mode to run IE6. The minimum supported version of IE on Windows 7 is IE8. Also, consider that IE is a component of Windows, not just another program, and that it can be updated like any other component but not downgraded like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run it as a virtual machine using an official IE testing image from Microsoft. You can use the free VirtualBox from Oracle. Download the official image from this site:

http://www.modern.ie/en-us/virtualization-tools#downloads

You would want to choose **Windows > VirtualBox on Windows** as your development environment, and you would want to download the **IE6 - XP** image.

Comment: If you are going to use a VM, you would probably be better off with Windows XP mode http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows7/install-and-use-windows-xp-mode-in-windows-7

Comment: I believe Windows XP mode is only available in the Professional/Ultimate/Enterprise editions http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/windows-xp-mode
The official IE testing images are available to everyone

Comment: Fair enough, I didn't realise that you could actually get the IE testing images for free as well. That's actually pretty cool.

Answer (score 19):

As has been noted in repeatedly in both comments and in other answers, you **CANNOT** install IE6 in Windows 7. Doesn't work. Don't even try, Don't waste your time. Even **IF** you could get IE 9 off this system, all you'd get would be IE 8 (that's what comes by default in Win7), and that **CANNOT** be uninstalled.

While some have suggested the complicated route of using virtualization, (which may be a good plan B, start at the very least with a much simpler plan A, compatibility mode)

A. Rather than trying to remove IE9 (which is NOT recommended) and trying to get some archaic browser installed, use compatibility mode. Simply press F12 in Internet Explorer at anytime.

[image: Compatibility Mode Menu]

Compatibility Mode will allow you make IE render pages as if they're an older version. They're like "Jedi Mind Tricks". It'll trick the website into thinking you're using an older version.

B. Try XP Mode in Win7. This little known FREE add-on to Win7 lets you run XP inside Windows 7.
**DOWNLOAD:** 
http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/features/windows-xp-mode

> It's the best of both worlds: The new Windows XP Mode lets you run older Windows XP business software right on your Windows 7 desktop.

I would say compatibility mode is a better route, it is a lot easier, and If I had to guess, most likely to work, but I also know XP Mode may also do the trick. XP Mode may take some more time, but it's guaranteed to work, it's a free VM for XP Microsoft lets 7 users download.

Answer (score 8):

Someone can prove me wrong, but IE6 will not install on Windows Vista or higher.
Microsoft does offer free Virtual PC images, specifically with each older version of IE (including IE6) for testing purposes.
They can be downloaded [here](http://search.microsoft.com/en-us/DownloadResults.aspx?FORM=DLC&ftapplicableproducts=%5e%22Internet%20Explorer%22&sortby=+weight).  They do expire after some amount of time, but you can keep redownloading them for free.

Comment: I think you're right. It wont install...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Virtual Machine in order to use IE6 in Windows XP (SP2 and below), by using VirtualBox or VirtualPC for free, even VMware Workstation.

Also, I don't know if there is a trial version of VMware ThinApp, but you can use it to allow IE6 to run in Windows Vista, 7 or 8 as a virtualized application. And this work like a charm ! ;)

Here are some links :

- VirtualBox : https://www.virtualbox.org/
- VirtualPC XP Mode : http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8002

Comment: If you are going to use a VM, you would probably be better off with Windows XP mode http://windows.microsoft.com/en-CA/windows7/install-and-use-windows-xp-mode-in-windows-7